# replace values in data frame based on pivot table values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the nan values in "Age columns" of a dataframe based on the values given in the pivot table,

"0 as female, 1 as male"

```
Example of df

Pclass Gender Age
  3      1     22
  1      0     38
  2      1     27
  3      0    NaN

Pivot table
            Age
    Gender 0  1
    PClass 
    1     40  35
    2     30  28
    3     25  21
```

for example, if the guy's age is missed, and if he/she is Pclass 3 and Gender 0, then his age is 25.

I have about 100 rows that needed to be updated, so is there a fast way?

Comment: please provide text (not image) of your df.  You can use df.to_dict() for example.

Comment: there are no `nan`s in the Age column...

Comment: I just updated the text

Answer (score 1):

You can use first create the `pivot_table` and merge it back with `df` with the additional column from pivoting and replace the values if `NaN` is observed

```
Example of df

Pclass Gender Age
  3      1     22
  1      0     38
  2      1     27
  3      0    NaN

Pivot table
            Age
    Gender 0  1
    PClass 
    1     40  35
    2     30  28
    3     25  21
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PClass','Gender','Age'])
df['PClass'] = [3,1,2,3]
df['Gender'] = [1,0,1,0]
df['Age'] = [22,38,27,np.nan]

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['PClass'],columns=['Gender'],values=['Age'],aggfunc='mean',fill_value=0) ### you can choose your own aggfunc
### I have taken `mean` here , but there ae a bunch of available options

df_pivot = df_pivot.unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Avg_Age_Pivot'})

df = pd.merge(df,df_pivot[['PClass','Gender','Avg_Age_Pivot']],on=['PClass','Gender'])

def replace_na(inp):
     inp = inp.values
     if pd.isnull(inp[0]):
        return inp[1]
     return inp[0]
 
 
df['Age'] = df[['Age','Avg_Age']].apply(replace_na,axis=1)
```

```
df _pivot O/P --->

>>> pd.pivot_table(df,index=['PClass'],columns=['Gender'],values=['Age'],aggfunc='mean') ### you can choose your own aggfunc
         Age      
Gender     0     1
PClass            
1       38.0   NaN
2        NaN  27.0
3        NaN  22.0
```

You can further decide to keep the `Avg_Age_Pivot` column or drop it.

Also I did noticed , with the amount of data you provided , there were `NaN` values in pivot_table , hence you my not see the desired result with the current `df` values

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I don't quite understand what do you mean by "NaN" values in pivot_table as there are 3x2 and 6 entries exactly.

Comment: Added the `df_pivot` output in the answer, For the pivot index where the data was itself not present , the aggfunc will return `NaN`

Comment: Oh I see! This is not the actual data, no worries. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the pivot table into a regular df

`pdf = pivot_table.stack().reset_index()`

then merge with the `nan` `df` and `combine_first`

```
nan_df = df.loc[df['Age'].isna(), ['Pclass', 'Gender']].merge(pdf, how='left')
df.set_index(['Pclass', 'Gender']).combine_first(nan_df.set_index(['Pclass', 'Gender'])).reset_index()
```

```
   Pclass  Gender   Age
0       1       0  38.0
1       2       1  27.0
2       3       0  25.0
3       3       1  22.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this approach. Created a common column called new by combining the 'PClass' and 'Gender' columns. Then used `map` and `df.fillna` to replace NaN values. I had to create this new column so because I can apply the `map` method only on `pd.series`.

Inputs:

```
import io
df1  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
PClass Gender Age
  3      1     22
  1      0     38
  2      1     27
  3      0    NaN
  """), sep=r"\s{1,}", engine="python") 

import io
df2  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
PClass  Gender Age
    1     0  40
    2     0  30
    3     0  25
    1     1  35
    2     1  28
    3     1  21
  """), sep=r"\s{1,}", engine="python")
```

df1 (Actual df)

```
  PClass  Gender   Age
0       3       1  22.0
1       1       0  38.0
2       2       1  27.0
3       3       0   NaN
```

df2 (Pivot table)

```
  PClass  Gender  Age
0       1       0   40
1       2       0   30
2       3       0   25
3       1       1   35
4       2       1   28
5       3       1   21
```

Code:

```
df1['new'] = df1['PClass'].astype(str)+df1['Gender'].astype(str)
df2['new'] = df2['PClass'].astype(str)+df2['Gender'].astype(str)
fill = df2.set_index(['new'])['Age'].to_dict()
df1['Age'] = df1['Age'].fillna(df1['new'].map(fill))
df1 = df1.drop('new',axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   PClass  Gender   Age
0       3       1  22.0
1       1       0  38.0
2       2       1  27.0
3       3       0  25.0
```